# Obtener varios datos de TXT con VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macros

espero se encuentren muy bien. Verán... Estoy trabajando con macros en excel el cual me permite obtener información de archivos TXT y poder utilizarlo en mi formato de excel. El contenido de mi TXT es el siguiente:

```
Replication Summary Start Time: 2019-04-30 10:26:26,,,,
Beginning data collection for replication summary, this may take awhile:,,  ....,,,,,,
Source DSA:Controlador de Dominio Principal          largest delta: 13m:17s    fails/total:0/10 %%   error,,,,,,
Destination DSA     largest delta    fails/total %%   error,,,,,,

Replication Summary Start Time: 2019-04-30 10:26:26,,,,
Beginning data collection for replication summary, this may take awhile:,,  ....,,,,,,
Source DSA:Controlador de dominio Secundario          largest delta: 12m:22s    fails/total:0/9 %%   error,,,,,,
Destination DSA     largest delta    fails/total %%   error,,,,,,

Replication Summary Start Time: 2019-04-30 10:26:27,,,,
Beginning data collection for replication summary, this may take awhile:,,  ....,,,,,,
Source DSA:Controlador de dominio terciario          largest delta: 11m:12s    fails/total:0/7 %%   error,,,,,,
Destination DSA     largest delta    fails/total %%   error,,,,,

    Sub texto()

    Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String, posLat As Integer, posLong As Integer, ntp As Integer

    myFile = "C:\Users\AngelEduardoMartinez\Documents\Archivo08.txt"
    Open myFile For Input As #1

    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, textline
        text = text & textline
    Loop

    Close #1
    source= InStr(text, "Source DSA")
    largest= InStr(text, "largest delta")
    fails= InStr(text, "fails/total")


    Range("A2").Value = Mid(text, source+ 11, 40)
    Range("B2").Value = Mid(text, largest+ 15, 10)
    Range("C2").Value = Mid(text, fails+ 12, 10)


    End Sub
```

Hasta aquí, con este código lo que hago es identificar en qué posición se encuentran los datos que quiero extraer y después con la función Mid obtengo la cadena en concreto.

El problema es que con `InStr` encuentro sólo la primer coincidencia que exista en el archivo y lo que pretendo es recuperar todas las coincidencias que existan dentro del txt para después poder copiar el contenido a las celdas de excel que les corresponda. Espero haber sido claro y puedan apoyarme, muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. El comando `InStr` te permite especificar una búsqueda desde una posición en concreto [Función InStr](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function). cuando encuentrs una coincidencia, te devuelve un número. Haz un bucle, y utiliza el número `fails` como posición inicial en la siguiente búsqueda, y así recorres todo. Cuando no encuentre nada, `InSTR` devolverá 0, y podrás salir de bucle.